# Error binding type variables in instance of typeclass

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I have a class "Shape" which should have "area" defined on all instances. area returns "Area b" (a data type) that contains a number (b belongs to Num typeclass) signifying the area of that Shape.

Haskell has problem binding that b to (x*y) where x and y are of type 'a' and 'a' is also of typeclass Num.
How do I solve this ?? [If i replace (x*y) by 0, it works but doesn't work even with (0::Int)]

Code :

```
data Unit = Unit | Meter | CentiMeter               deriving Show

data Area a = Area a Unit                           deriving Show

class Shape a where
      area :: (Num b) => a -> Area b

data Rectangle side = Rectangle side side Unit  deriving Show

instance (Num a) => Shape (Rectangle a) where
     area (Rectangle x y unit) = Area (x*y) unit
```

Error :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( y.hs, interpreted )

y.hs:11:46:
    Could not deduce (a ~ b)
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the instance declaration at y.hs:10:10-39
    or from (Num b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 area :: Num b => Rectangle a -> Area b
      at y.hs:11:10-52
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at y.hs:10:15
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for area :: Num b => Rectangle a -> Area b
          at y.hs:11:10
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `y'
    In the first argument of `Area', namely `(x * y)'
    In the expression: Area (x * y) unit
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is `area`'s type signature:

```
area :: (Num b) => a -> Area b
```

What it says is "give me an `a`, and I'll give you an `Area b` for *any* `b` you want; you can pick". So, for instance, I could give `area` an `Integer` and expect back an `Area Double`. Clearly, this isn't what you want!

In this case, the error arises because you use `x*y`, which has type *a*, when *b* is expected — you have to give a value that works for *any* numeric type *b*, but you're giving a value that only works for one (*a*).

If you changed `area`'s type to `a -> Area Integer`, or such, then it would work. However, I have a feeling you want the *instance* to be able to specify what the type of the area is. For this, you'll need to use a language extension called [*type families*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class (Num (AreaComponent a)) => Shape a where
    type AreaComponent a
    area :: a -> Area (AreaComponent a)

instance (Num a) => Shape (Rectangle a) where
    type AreaComponent (Rectangle a) = a
    area (Rectangle x y unit) = Area (x*y) unit
```

This says that for every type *a* that's an instance of `Shape`, there is an *associated type* `AreaComponent a`, representing the type of each component of its area. That type is required to be an instance of `Num` by the definition of `Shape`.

Another thing you could do, if all your shapes take a numeric type parameter, is to make the instances be for the type constructors of each shape, rather than the full shape types themselves:

```
class Shape sh where
    area :: (Num a) => sh a -> Area a

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle x y unit) = Area (x*y) unit
```

Comment: Have to read about type families as I was thinking in similar direction.

Comment: But your second solution is too good and works for my current needs.

Comment: @Karan: Great! If my answer helped you, you should click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
class Shape a where
      area :: (Num b) => a -> Area b
```

promises to be able to deliver any `Num` type that the caller might want, but your implementation just provides some `Num` type the callee provides.

The only way to produce numbers of any desired type is to use `fromInteger` (or literals, wher `fromInteger` is implicit).

To be able to deliver some `Num` type determined by the type of thing whose area is to be computed, you can use multi parameter type classes and functional dependencies or type families, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Shape a where
    type NumType a :: *
    area :: a -> Area (NumType a)

instance (Num side) => Shape (Rectangle side) where
    type NumType (Rectangle side) = side
    area (Rectangle w h u) = Area (w*h) u
```